# Change name of apk depending on buildType

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to change the name of my output .apk files. However, I want to have "-debug" or "-release" appended depending on the build type.

Here are the output names I want:
MyApp-0.0.1-debug.apk
MyApp-0.0.1-release.apk

I'm unfamiliar with Gradle and haven't found how to do this, I know I just need to access the buildType within the following code but can't find how to do this.

Currently my output is "MyApp-0.0.1.apk" regardless of buildType. How can I change the code below to alter this?

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def outputFile = output.outputFile
    if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {

        def fileName
        def bType = ""
        // bType = "-" + something.buildType

        fileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${project.version}${bType}.aar"
        output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone arriving here late, this version works for me in **April 2020**.

Just place this code inside your `buildTypes` element ( `android` or `defaultConfig` work just as well).

```kotlin
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      def customBuildName = ""
      if(variant.buildType.name == "release") customBuildName = "release-name.apk"
      else customBuildName = "build-name.apk"
      variant.outputs.all {
          outputFileName = customBuildName
      println("name of ${variant.buildType.name} build is ${outputFileName}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The build type is part of the variant; you're iterating over all the variants in your loop. You can get the build type name via:

```
variant.buildType.name
```

You can find (partially complete) API docs at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide